# Согласование падежей

Tags: согласование

Они называют научные конференции именами учёных: Иванов(а), Петров(а)...
В каком падеже должны быть эти имена? В именительном или родительном?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они называют научные конференции именами учёных (Р.п.): **Иванова, Петрова** (Р.п).

Имена составляют однородный ряд и согласуются в Р.п. с обобщающим словом ***учёных***.